# I have a question about the best way to solve a query on Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, calculated-field

I have a dataset where customers have multiple activities under one ID. I already have a count for how many jobs were done (Job done") but what I would like to know is out of all those jobs done, which ones had an appointment booked with "India" as the officer. Below is sample data, realistically I have multiple rows of this but some without Appointments booked or by India.
[image]

I created a calculated table and tried a DAX function which looked at the earlier customer ID and filtered for the activities and officer but it slows down the processing tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Showing what you tried and is slow would help a lot!

I think the way to do this is to use INTERSECT, except I'm not clear on how you deal with a customer having multiple sets of events.
You could use INTERSECT(Set A, Set B)
Then you could create one set as "JobComplete" as FILTER('Events',[Activities]="Job Complete")

and the other set as OfficerJulia = FILTER('Events',[Officer]='Julia')

So finally INTERSECT(JobComplete, OfficerJulia)